# widgetVar cannot be used in p:fileUpload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, widget

I want to remove the error message when choosing a wrong type of file. I followed the link http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23853 .

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{userProfileUpdateController.upload}"         
    widgetVar="fileuplaodWgt"                     
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
    description="Select Images"
    update="userPhoto"
    mode="advanced"/>
```

and I import `<h:outputScript name="library.js" library="script"></h:outputScript>`

In library.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(fileuplaodWgt);
   fileuplaodWgt.buttonBar.find("button.cancel").bind("click", function(e){
   clearInvalidFileMsg();
    });
});

function clearInvalidFileMsg(){
    fileuplaodWgt.uploadContent.find("tr.ui-state-error").remove();
 }
```

After writing above, file upload is not shown in my page. When I trace the my library.js file, I found **fileuplaodWgt ReferenceError: fileuplaodWgt is not defined**. I tried in mozilla and chrome. None of them shows my file upload. Can you help me what I am wrong???

Comment: On the link what you posted `widgetVar` is `fileuplaod_wgt` but in this code `fileuplaodWgt`. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: No..I first tried with fileuplaod_wgt. But it no works. So I changed to fileuplaodWgt.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the naming except when the `fileupload` `id` is the same as `widgetVar`, that may conflict. I would do a quick search/replace for `fileuplaod_wgt` maybe you left something unchanged. I would also try to reference fileuplaodWgt through `window.fileuplaodWgt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces initializes widget vars on DOM ready as well by `$(function())`. The `<script>` containing the command is rendered directly after the component. So, if your `$(document).ready()` is invoked *before* the widget var one, then it won't find the widget var because it's initialized later. You need to ensure that your `$(document).ready()` is invoked *after* the component is rendered. One of the ways is relocating the script to the end of HTML `<body>` by `target="body"`.

```
<h:outputScript name="library.js" library="script" target="body" />
```

This way the script is loaded and initialized when the end of document is reached, thus *after* all widget var initializations.

Another way is to use `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`, but this is clumsy and potentially slower as it's only invoked when all images referenced in the document are loaded.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way you're using the resource `library` is not right. Please carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) and just use

```
<h:outputScript name="script/library.js" target="body" />
```

You've by the way also a disturbing typo in the widget var name not further related to the problem. It's *upload*, not *uplaod*.